HMAC Verification getting failed, python - shopify app
I am working on a python project to make shopify app, but i am failing to verify hmac, my received hmac and calculated hmac is not getting matched, i am uploading a function verify_hmac and function callback
def verify_hmac(params, secret):
    # Extract the HMAC
    received_hmac = params.get('hmac')
    
    if not received_hmac:
        print("Received HMAC is empty.")
        return False

    # Sort the parameters and exclude the 'hmac'
    sorted_params = {key: params[key][0] for key in sorted(params) if key != 'hmac'}

    # Rebuild the message string for HMAC verification
    message = "&".join([f"{quote_plus(key)}={quote_plus(value)}" for key, value in sorted_params.items()])

    # Calculate the HMAC
    calculated_hmac = hmac.new(secret.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    print("Received HMAC:", received_hmac)
    print("Calculated HMAC:", calculated_hmac)

    # Compare the received HMAC with the calculated HMAC
    return hmac.compare_digest(received_hmac, calculated_hmac)

def callback(request):
    # Log all received parameters
    print("Received parameters:", request.GET)

    shop = request.GET.get('shop')
    code = request.GET.get('code')

    if not shop or not code:
        return HttpResponse("Missing shop or code in callback", status=400)

    # Setup the Shopify API
    api_key = os.getenv('SHOPIFY_API_KEY')
    secret = os.getenv('SHOPIFY_API_SECRET')

    # Debug output to check if API Key and Secret are loaded
    print("API Key:", api_key)
    print("Secret:", secret)

    # Verify HMAC with try-except for error handling
    try:
        if not verify_hmac(request.GET, secret):
            return HttpResponse("HMAC verification failed", status=403)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error during HMAC verification:", str(e))
        return HttpResponse("Internal server error", status=500)

    # Proceed to request token if HMAC verification is successful
    return HttpResponse("HMAC verification passed.")

This is what it is showing on terminal:
Received parameters: <QueryDict: {'code': ['*****************************'], 'hmac': ['72958cddad5aff5b9109be7ab13c88cb9d9ed09fe01367a189214f518b171041'], 'host': ['YWRtaW4uc2hvcGlmeS5jb20vc3RvcmUvYmFyb21vbmRvdGVzdA'], 'shop': ['baromondotest.myshopify.com'], 'timestamp': ['1728913017']}>

API Key: *******************************

Secret: ********************************

Received HMAC: 72958cddad5aff5b9109be7ab13c88cb9d9ed09fe01367a189214f518b171041

Calculated HMAC: 61d44f23aac3fc4b6ece0eea6a8d9685e2aa315b468eadc7db0c91f8316b7f95

On browser it is showing

HMAC verification failed

